# How does the induction principle for the singleton type unit in Coq work?

Tags: coq

I was going through Adam Chlipala's book on Coq and it defined the inductive type:

```
Inductive unit : Set :=
  | tt.
```

I was trying to understand its induction principle:

```
Check unit_ind.
(* unit_ind
     : forall P : unit -> Prop, P tt -> forall u : unit, P u *)
```

I am not sure if I understand what the output of Coq means.

1) So check gives me a look at the type of "objects" right? So `unit_ind` has type:

```
forall P : unit -> Prop, P tt -> forall u : unit, P u
```

Right?

2) How does one read that type? I am having trouble understanding where to put the parenthesis or something...For the first thing before the comma, it doesn't make sense to me to read it as:

```
IF "for all P of type unit" THEN " Prop "
```

since the hypothesis is not really something true or false. So I assume the real way to real the first thing is this way:

```
forall P : (unit -> Prop), ...
```

so P is just a function of type unit to prop. Is this correct?

I wish this was correct but under that interpretation I don't know how to read the part after the first comma:

```
P tt -> forall u : unit, P u
```

I would have expected all the quantifications of variables in existence to be defined at the beginning of the proposition but thats not how its done, so I am not sure what is going on...

Can someone help me read this proposition both formally and intuitively? I also want to understand conceptually what it's trying to say and not only get bugged down by the details of it.

Answer (score 5):

Let me put some extra (not really necessary) parentheses:

```
forall P : unit -> Prop, P tt -> (forall u : unit, P u)
```

I would translate it as "For any predicate `P` over the `unit` type, if `P` holds of `tt`, then `P` holds of any term of type `unit`".

Intuitively, since `tt` is the only value of type `unit`, it makes sense to only prove `P` for this unique value.

You can check if this intuition works for you by trying to interpret the induction principle for the `bool` type in the same manner.

```
Check bool_ind.
bool_ind
     : forall P : bool -> Prop, P true -> P false -> (forall b : bool, P b)
```